# sound not playing at the right moment

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I created a **MediaElement** for a **Background Music** in my Windows Phone App and it plays perfectly
now the problem when I tried to add sound for  a button **when pressed**

When I debug , the **Background music plays** , but when I **press** the button it **navigates** me to the next page **without playing** the sound I created, and when I press **BackButton** from the **Navigated Page**, it plays it, why?

code:

```
private void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaElement Click = new MediaElement();
    Click.Source = new Uri ("/Assets/Sounds/press.mp3",UriKind.Relative);
    Click.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
    Click.Volume = 1;
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Click);
    Click.Play();
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NavPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: Use Background audio player instead of MediaElement to play sound in background. MediaElement doesn't work in background.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement Click = new MediaElement();
            Click.Source = new Uri ("/Assets/Sounds/press.mp3",UriKind.Relative);
            Click.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
            Click.Volume = 1;
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Click);
            Click.Play();

        }
```

you should handle this outside button click,

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NavPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Add an event handler to the click and call separately,

```
 Click.MediaEnded += Click_Completed;

 void Click_Completed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NavPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

Comment: But i need to navigate to that page when i press the button "Play"

Comment: i modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

or you can make MediaEnded event of the mediaElement and there in you can call the navigation

Like this:

```
private void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement Click = new MediaElement();
            Click.Source = new Uri ("/Assets/Sounds/press.mp3",UriKind.Relative);
            Click.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
            Click.Volume = 1;
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Click);
            Click.MediaEnded += Click_MediaEnded;
            Click.Play();
        }

void Click_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NavPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
       }
```

Comment: okay that works , but now i cant navigate back when i press back button , because when i press backbutton it plays the click sound again ( Shouldn't be played ) and navigates again to NavPage

Comment: at which you were while you pressed the backbutton, NavPage or the page at which you are defining click media? and are you overriding back button code?

Comment: @Romasz but the media element is getting initialized on a button click, does that means that the play_Click is automatically getting fired?

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal Yes, you are right (so I deleted the comment). Try to check if changing Click.AutoPlay helps.